# How to use Privoxy in conjunction with SOCKS proxy?

Tags: socks-proxy, privoxy

After configuring my browser to use SOCKS5 proxy Privoxy stopped working with the application. How can I fix the proxy chain?

example settings:
SOCKS host: `127.0.0.1`
port: `8118`

Comment: Make your browser use Privoxy and not some other proxy. Privoxy would have to be setup to use he SOCKS proxy.

Comment: @Seth: You can provide a method for doing so as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Privoxy Frequently Asked Questions: Configuration](https://www.privoxy.org/faq/configuration.html)

> **3.17. How can I make Privoxy work with other proxies?**
>
> This can be done and is often useful to combine the benefits of Privoxy with those of a another proxy, for example to cache content. See the forwarding chapter in the User Manual which describes how to do this. If you intend to use Privoxy with Tor, please also have a look at How do I use Privoxy together with Tor.

[Privoxy 3.0.26 User Manual: 7.5. Forwarding](https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html#FORWARDING)

> This feature allows routing of HTTP requests through a chain of multiple proxies.
>
> ...
>
> **7.5.2. forward-socks4, forward-socks4a, forward-socks5 and forward-socks5t**
>
> ...
>
> Type of value:
>
> target_pattern socks_proxy[:port] http_parent[:port]

Configuration example without HTTP parent:

```
forward-socks5   /               socks-gw.example.com:1080  .
```

Comment: Quick question: would it be difficult to manually write a `http <---> socks5` conversion program? I mean, you just need to wrap the `http` level data with `socks` protocol in some way. That would be easy, right? : (

Comment: That would depend on your skill and your knowledge of the protocols. It might be quick or it might not be. There are dozens of approaches with existing solutions that are ready to use. There is no simple answer for your question and while it should be posted as an independent question, currently it lacks detail to do that. Maybe do some research and post a [good individual](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) question as it might be interesting.